# Update MS Access with new rows in MySql in linked table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, office365

I'm using MySql and MS Access 365. I have successfully linked a table in Access to my Mysql database using the odbc unicode driver, and updating any value in either MS access or mysql automatically updates in the other.

My problem is that adding a new row in mysql does not show up in access unless I close the table and open it again.  Is there any way I can have the table update with new rows added?  If I programmatically close and reopen the table will it cause people to loose their place?  I'd prefer to find some way to just have the table update and show the new rows.

Comment: You need to refresh link. Do right click on tables, you should have a option to do it on theme menu

Comment: Don't show tables use forms (with a query to the table as `Record Source`), The `Form.Requery` method,  executes the query again to fetch the new records starting with the first row, but you can use a [Bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-bookmark-property-dao) to return to the last selected record. Unfortunally this only cares about the selected record, not the position of the scrollbar in a Contious Form (if you select the first row and then scroll down , the bookmark is still the first row)

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto, I did a right click on the linked table and selected both "refresh link" and "relink" (the relink option was within the Linked Table Manager option), neither one displayed the new row I inserted into the table.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto mixed up rows with columns. To get new inserts you have to requery.